# Flink AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class

Tags: scala, apache-kafka, apache-flink, avro, confluent-schema-registry

I try to use the confluent schema registry in an interactive Flink Scala shell to get started with the current 0.10.1 version of Flink.
Further context is available here https://github.com/geoHeil/streaming-reference/tree/5-basic-flink-setup

My problem is trying to initialize the serializer from the `ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema` fails:

```
val serializer = ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific[Tweet](classOf[Tweet], schemaRegistryUrl)
error: type arguments [Tweet] conform to the bounds of none of the overloaded alternatives of
value forSpecific: [T <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord](x$1: Class[T], x$2: String, x$3: Int)org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema[T] <and> [T <: org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificRecord](x$1: Class[T], x$2: String)org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema[T]
```

The shell is set up like (i.e. additional JARs for avro or schema registry support are added as follows below:):

```
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kafka_2.11/1.10.1/flink-connector-kafka_2.11-1.10.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-connector-kafka-base_2.11/1.10.1/flink-connector-kafka-base_2.11-1.10.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/kafka/kafka-clients/0.10.2.1/kafka-clients-0.10.2.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-avro-confluent-registry/1.10.1/flink-avro-confluent-registry-1.10.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/flink-avro/1.10.1/flink-avro-1.10.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/flink/force-shading/1.10.1/force-shading-1.10.1.jar -P lib/
wget https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/avro/avro/1.8.2/avro-1.8.2.jar -P lib/

export TERM=xterm-color
./bin/start-scala-shell.sh local
```

I try to execute the following snippet:

```
import org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.{
  FlinkKafkaConsumer,
  FlinkKafkaProducer
}
import org.apache.flink.formats.avro.registry.confluent.ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema
import java.util.Properties

senv.enableCheckpointing(5000)

final case class Tweet(tweet_id: Option[String], text: Option[String], source: Option[String], geo: Option[String], place: Option[String], lang: Option[String], created_at: Option[String], timestamp_ms: Option[String], coordinates: Option[String], user_id: Option[Long], user_name: Option[String], screen_name: Option[String], user_created_at: Option[String], followers_count: Option[Long], friends_count: Option[Long], user_lang: Option[String], user_location: Option[String], hashtags: Option[Seq[String]])

val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092")
properties.setProperty("group.id", "test")
val schemaRegistryUrl = "http://localhost:8081"
val serializer = ConfluentRegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.forSpecific[Tweet](classOf[Tweet], schemaRegistryUrl)
```

http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/no-subject-td36269.html and http://apache-flink-user-mailing-list-archive.2336050.n4.nabble.com/Avro-from-avrohugger-still-invalid-td36274.html are links to Flinks mailing list

### edit

The first hint I have stumbled upon is: https://github.com/zladovan/gradle-avrohugger-plugin I need to change the case classes to one of Avro Specfic or generic record when generating the classes. But I am also struggling there to get it working.

The `case class Tweet` example from above was generated from https://github.com/geoHeil/streaming-reference/blob/5-basic-flink-setup/common/models/src/main/avro/Tweet.avsc using https://github.com/zladovan/gradle-avrohugger-plugin in standard (i.e. case class) mode.

However, it needs to be moved to `SpecificRecord` format https://github.com/zladovan/gradle-avrohugger-plugin#source-formats to have a `Tweet` class which is compatible. This one is rather lengthy. For completeness it is available at https://gist.github.com/geoHeil/8b15d44d07e11c32a461b78365e0c158

The job is now still failing with:

```
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: class com.github.geoheil.streamingreference.Tweet
```

even for an arguably compatible class. So this is not (yet) a full solution. Even though according to https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-12501 it should already work:

```
org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: avro.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: class com.github.geoheil.streamingreference.Tweet
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:227)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.AvroDeserializationSchema.checkAvroInitialized(AvroDeserializationSchema.java:147)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.checkAvroInitialized(RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.java:79)
    at org.apache.flink.formats.avro.RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.deserialize(RegistryAvroDeserializationSchema.java:64)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internals.KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.deserialize(KafkaDeserializationSchemaWrapper.java:45)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.internal.KafkaFetcher.runFetchLoop(KafkaFetcher.java:140)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.connectors.kafka.FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.run(FlinkKafkaConsumerBase.java:718)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:100)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.api.operators.StreamSource.run(StreamSource.java:63)
    at org.apache.flink.streaming.runtime.tasks.SourceStreamTask$LegacySourceFunctionThread.run(SourceStreamTask.java:200)
Caused by: avro.shaded.com.google.common.util.concurrent.UncheckedExecutionException: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: class com.github.geoheil.streamingreference.Tweet
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2234)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.get(LocalCache.java:3965)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache.getOrLoad(LocalCache.java:3969)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LocalManualCache.get(LocalCache.java:4829)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.getSchema(SpecificData.java:225)
    ... 9 more
Caused by: org.apache.avro.AvroRuntimeException: Not a Specific class: class com.github.geoheil.streamingreference.Tweet
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData.createSchema(SpecificData.java:285)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData$2.load(SpecificData.java:218)
    at org.apache.avro.specific.SpecificData$2.load(SpecificData.java:215)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$LoadingValueReference.loadFuture(LocalCache.java:3568)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.loadSync(LocalCache.java:2350)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.lockedGetOrLoad(LocalCache.java:2313)
    at avro.shaded.com.google.common.cache.LocalCache$Segment.get(LocalCache.java:2228)
    ... 13 more
```

Comment: From the Mailinglist: https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18478;  unfortunately, it seems I only fixed the issue for AvroSerializer and
not for AvroDeserializationSchema

Comment: A fix is merged as of today and should be part of any of the next Flink releases.

Comment: But this fix as available of 1.11.1 does not solve all problems. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/FLINK-18693 is still open.